# typed-Dataset VS Own access Database classes

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, strongly-typed-dataset

Hi i would like to know if it's better to use typed-dataset rather than Own access with Datareader and Store procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Typed Datasets are alwaya a better option compared to using plain DataReaders.**

Typed datasets gets you,

- abstraction over SQL queries and StoredProcedures and you call them by making function calls.
- freedom from managing connection-strings
- typed rerpresentation of each table which adds a great deal for type-safety at compile-time.
- and much more..

Answer (score 1):

in typed dataset you will have to use stored procedure or normal queries to make transactions or selected data. the difference is that in typed dataset the data types and format are strongly defined and named, but in datareader you have create your objects and do the casting for each row you read. 
so it depends on your project requirements and what it suits better. it varies from implementation to other.